# Get Excel property by name

Tags: c#, .net, excel, charts

I'm working in c# and I'm passing in chart properties as a json string, for example:

```
{'chart':{
'series':{
    'count':3,
    'style':'3 Series Scaled Bars',
    'data':[
        {'x':'Brand','y':'Avg Comments','type':'barScaled','position':1}
        {'x':'Brand','y':'Avg Likes','type':'barScaled','position':2}
        {'x':'Brand','y':'Avg Shares','type':'barScaled','position':3}
    ]
}}}
```

What I'd like to be able to do is pass in something like this: 'markerSize': 8 and be able to set the property with the string name of the property, something likes this:

```
Excel.SeriesCollection lines = (Excel.SeriesCollection)chrt.SeriesCollection();
Excel.Series ser = sers.Item(1);
ser.Properties("markerSize") = 8;
```

Is that possible, or do I have to write code to handle each property that I need to be able to modify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System.Reflection class may provide what you seek for.

In case some of properties will be in fact fields following code handles both situations.
For COM objects it supports only properties, I am too tired to think of a way to support both fields and properties for COM objects without ugly try-catch blocks.

Why previous code failed for Interop objects? Because they are evil COM objects.
While Reflection can normally return fields and properties for interface without any problem, for COM objects it failed because their true type during runtime is System._*ComObject, which of course lacked properties you were looking for.
Workaround is to use Invoke method, which deals with horrors of COM on its own.
System.*_ComObject is hidden type, hence its tested as string instead of Type. (I am tired)

```
using System.Reflection;
...
    /// <summary>
    /// Dynamicaly sets property of given object with given value. No type casting is required. Supports COM objects properties.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="target">targeted object</param>
    /// <param name="propertyName">property name</param>
    /// <param name="value">desired value</param>
    /// <returns>True if success, False if failure (non existing member)</returns>
    static bool SetProperty(object target, string propertyName, object value)
    {
        Type t = target.GetType();
        if(t.ToString()=="System.__ComObject")
        {
            t.InvokeMember(propertyName, BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, target, new object[] { value });
            return true;
        }
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = t.GetProperty(propertyName);
        FieldInfo fieldInfo = t.GetField(propertyName);
        if (propertyInfo != null)
        {
            propertyInfo.SetValue(target, Convert.ChangeType(value, propertyInfo.PropertyType, null));
            return true;
        }
        if (fieldInfo!=null)
        {
            fieldInfo.SetValue(target, Convert.ChangeType(value, fieldInfo.FieldType, null));
            return true;
        }            
        return false;
    }

//usage:
foo bar = new foo();
SetProperty(bar,"myPropertyOrField","myValue");
```

Comment: I implemented.  propertyInfo always ends up null.  Doing this:

`Debug.Print(((Excel.Series)target).Name)`

will print the current name of the chart series, but I can't seem to get the propertyInfo set so that I can use SetValue() on it.

Comment: @TrickySam: Issue is... weird. I managed to pinpoint it, understand it and then make workaround. I will post results in a while, first I need to turn my temporary code into something I won't be ashamed to show. ;)

Comment: I appreciate your help.  Did you have any luck with this?  What was the issue?

Comment: I updated answer already, issue was with Interop objects reporting themselves as "System.__ComObject" so they require to be treated as such, for example by hitting them in face with InvokeMember. This time I tested it on interop object before posting. ;)

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't see it.  This works perfectly.  Anyway, thanks for this and for that invoke trick.  I'm going to be using that in the future.  I deal with a lot of "evil COM objects", haha.

Comment: Good to know, I am not sure (as in, not tested) how it will deal with raw variable, but I think that all COM interfaces are packed at least in default {get; set;} so it should go all right... probably.